# Firefox outline rendering wrong

Tags: html, css, firefox

On a site I am building I am using a border - outline - box shadow for the body.

See here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hn9vh/)

```
border: 9px solid #0C144E;
outline: 9px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 18px #CC092F;
```

My problem is that Firefox renders the outline differently.

I can get around it by applying:

```
outline-offset: -18px;
```

Although it fixes firefox, this means that it doesn't display correctly in Chrome, Safari, is there a way to apply it to firefox only I tried adding -moz- to no avail. Or another way around it.

Comment: The double-border effect you're trying to achieve looks *very* similar to one from a question I answered a few days ago -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219056/multiple-borders-around-a-div-with-a-transparent-layer/18219591#18219591. I used CSS `:before` to create a double-border effect. Here's the fiddle I created for that answer: http://jsfiddle.net/k8v7D/

Comment: If that technique is suitable for you, then I'd suggest using it in favour of using a browser hack as per your accepted answer; browser hacks should always be the last resort (because if it's a FF bug, what happens if Mozilla fix the bug in the next version?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the technique showed here: [CSS Hacks Targeting Firefox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/)

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  body {
    outline-offset: -18px;
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hn9vh/1/)

Comment: Thank you for that hack!